# Limit a new user privileges

Tags: permissions, xubuntu

I created a new user and i want it to have limited privileges. I don't want it to be able to go to /home and see all the other users nor interact with them. Until now it's able to access /home and i didn't find on the web any available solutions, they all teach me how to grant root privileges while i need to downgrade them.
**I use xubuntu 20.04**

Comment: Doing this is not very easy. It is normal that a user has access to /home because that's important - the user could not enter it's own home (/home/user) if there's no x-privilege.

Comment: @france1 You can remove `r` privilege on `/home` and leave the `x` only. The user will be able to access his/her `/home/userid` but will not be able to list contents of `/home`.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want it to be able to go to /home and see all the other users nor interact with them.

This consists of 2 parts:

You will not be able to prevent a user from seeing its own /home/. If you could that would prevent the user from logging into the system. Mind that if a user is not allowed inside its own home that user should not have access to that system.

- What you could do is create a user and treat it as a guest: when this user logs in delete all content in the normal directories in this /home/.

The second part is already the case: a user can NOT access another users /home/ since both user and group of all users are different. The "others" for directories in /home/ is set to `---` so  no read, no write, and no execute permissions.

Mind that this is for normal users, not admins.

Comment: As for the 1st part, you can remove `r` privilege on `/home` (not `/home/user`, but the parent `/home` - if that is what OP meant) and leave the `x` only. The user will be able to access his/her `/home/userid` but will not be able to list contents of `/home`.